# Getting "Request aborted" exception if REST operation takes more than 2mins

Tags: c#, rest, httprequest, restsharp

I have a server written in python that runs on WSL. I communicate with it from C# via REST api. The service `do` that's called via `_restClient.PostAsync` can take a few seconds or a few minutes. Sometimes `_restClient.PostAsync` throws `Request aborted` exception though the service **always** completes on the server side without any errors.

It seems like some kind of timeout or keep-a-live issue.
As part of the debugging process I replaced the code of the `do` service on the server side with just `time.sleep`. And it turns out that if it sleeps for more than 2min then I get this error on the client side. Meaning if the `do` logic on the server side takes more than 2 min then on its completion `_restClient.PostAsync` throws `Request aborted` exception. What can be the issue? Do I need to configure something?

**Error**

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Request aborted ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at RestSharp.RestClient.<ExecuteRequestAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RestSharp.ResponseThrowExtension.ThrowIfError[T](RestResponse`1 response)
   at RestSharp.RestClientExtensions.<PostAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
```

**Code**

```
public class MyService
{
    public MyService(...)
    {
        _restClient = new RestSharp.RestClient(url);
    }

    public async Task DoAsync()
    {   
        try
        {   
            var request = new RestRequest("do");
            request.AddJsonBody(/*data*/);
            var res = await _restClient.PostAsync<int>(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

            ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log
            throw;
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: _"What can be the issue? Do I need to configure something?"_ - Requests are not supposed to take forever. Quite the opposite. If you have long running tasks then there are patterns for that. But the initial Request must still return fast. One solution I've seen in practice was that the starting POST request registered a long running process with the server and returned a "Ticket Number" along with uris to check the status and finally GET the result when finished. A later iteration also included a WebHook to get notified instead of polling status. IDK if that's still "how you do it", though.

Comment: I don't set any timeout as you see in the code. So, is there any internal timeout that being set by the library or http request itself?

Comment: There usually is, yes. But I would have to dig, too to tell which one is about 2 minutes. And as I said: I don't think it's a particularly good idea to extend that timeout. _If your use-case fits_, you maybe want to investigate "long-polling".

Comment: Isn't using "long-polling" might also timeout as it cannot keep connection very long and depends on implementation, library and so on? Probably the solution is to use something like Websocket or even something based on http/2 like grpc so it will keep connection as long as needed and notify me asynchronously once it completed the request, right?

Comment: @theateist What is the average response time? Is the 2 mins response time considered normal or outlier?

Comment: the response time is whatever takes the server to complete `do` service. It can be seconds, 5min, 30min or even 1 hour. So, it seems HttpRequest has a default timeout of 100 seconds. So, should I use something like Websocket or even something based on http/2 like grpc so it will keep connection as long as needed and notify me asynchronously once it completed the request?